# if I put 2 ,and then printf the outcome will be n=2 m=8 q=32 why?

Tags: c, scanf

I enter 2 into `scanf` but 3 number output? why?

[image]

I tried 2

```
 scanf("%d", &n, &m, &q);
```

but 3 number output

why?

Comment: I enter 2 the outcome is n=2 m=8 q=32 why?

Comment: you have 3 variables but only 1 format specifier

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Post your code as plain text, not an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for code formatting help.

Answer (score 2):

Since you only have one `%d` in your `scanf` format string, it only reads one number, and puts that into the first variable `n`.

When you printed the variables with

```
printf("m%d n%d q%d", m, n, q);
```

it prints 3 numbers because you have `%d` 3 times in the format string.

It prints `n2` because that's the value you entered. The other two variables have indeterminate values because you never initialized them and `scanf()` didn't have a format operator to fill them in.

Answer (score 1):

If you say `scanf("%d", ... );` you can read and store only one number because you have single `%d`. If you have one number to read him only write `scanf("%d", &m );`, if you want to read two numbers then write `scanf("%d%d", &m,&n );`, for three numbers `scanf("%d%d%d", &m,&n,&q );`, ...